# AngularJS: inline/embed css and js in html or not

Tags: html, css, angularjs, gruntjs, gulp

I have a dilema, I'm thinking about best way of return my index.html. I have 2 ways:

Way 1: Index with a script tag for javascript concat and minified file. The same with CSS.

Way 2: Index with inline css and js code minified and concat.

The second way no make extra requests, but I think that this not can be store in browser cache, maybe the html not will be stored in cache? I'm not sure of this. Thats right this?

What way will be better for do in my grunt/gulp config script if i want the best way to optimize.

Comment: Every web document can be cached by the browser, including images, HTML, JS and CSS. I'd recommend you to use separated files, so you can use the scripts and styles among the different pages with less cost, once the file is cached.

Comment: If you have a Single Page Application, you would probably prefer only one file.

Comment: Yes, it's a SPA (Single page application), I don't need reuse scripts. Thanks for information, I will use the first way.